# A way to include SQlite into an application where the drivers aren't already installed on the system?

Tags: php, web-applications, storage, sqlite

I'm an open source web application for use in my university.  Currently professors usually have a website, but do to the fact that they're teaching multiple classes in a given term, they don't care to spend time and make an extensible, functional website.

The purpose of this project is to create an OSS website that can be dropped in place and enabled by simply running an init.php file.

I'm curious though as how to handle information storage for such a task.  A full server database is a bit outside of the scope I'm looking for, but something like SQlite would fit very well.

The problem I'm running into is that not all departments have SQlite installed on their servers, and getting them all to do so won't happen.

Can anyone think of a way to include SQlite into an application where the drivers aren't already installed on the system, or a more common alternative that would provide a similar level of power/flexibility?

Comment: SQLite is an outboard DLL, not a device driver. Drop the DLL into the application folder, and see what happens.  Your school may need to give the DLL permissions, but no installation is required.

Comment: Don't you just need one server with a database installed on the server for all the sites to use? Seems like they're all on the same network?

Comment: @Jeffo: Not really.  Every department has its own database, and they are not all using the same engines.  I don't have access to each department that may want to use this application.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have this tagged as PHP...

For PHP versions 5.0 up to but not including 5.4, SQLite was included in PHP by default.  So there's nothing to install unless your particular build was compiled specifically not to include it.

For later versions, you'll need to install the SQLite extension.  On linux you can do this by installing the php5-sqlite3 package.

Comment: Based on your comment I did a little more checking and did a printout of phpinfo().  Looks like mysql and odbc are the only drivers enabled for PDO.

Sqlite has been removed entirely :/

Comment: What version of php is it?  It looks like the bundling of sqlite was recently changed.

Comment: PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze17 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 23 2013 15:06:16)

Comment: See my above edit - they may need to install & enable the php-sqlite package.  Since they have MySQL installed, you might consider just using that.  That'd give you better application support since essentially every open source system php project that uses a database defaults to mysql.